# Can you visit this place in Deponia?

Tags: deponia

In the bonus material of **Deponia**, I found the following screenshot:

[image: Deponia screenshot 004]

I can't remember visiting this place.

Is it in the game actually? Or did it never make it to the finished version?

Comment: I just looked through the bonus material, and didn't see this.  Where did you find this?

Comment: @Blueraja-DannyPflughoeft: In the file "24 artworks" from the [version on gog.com](https://secure.gog.com/gamecard/deponia).

Comment: Oh, I think it might have been the file "concept art" instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't remember this from the game either.  However, Goal gets locked up a similar machine in the sequel, *Chaos on Deponia*:

[image: Doc's workshop]

I bet this was an old prototype of Doc's workshop that got cut from the first game and altered for the second.